# How to convert a character to hex in Python

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I have a key that has two-first bytes, and I want to go through ascii to figure out those two bytes:

```
b'\x9aF\x95=A?\xef\xc3a*\xdb :\xc6\x1bC'
```

However, I am not sure how to convert the characters like, a, b, c, etc. to the same format, so I can receive the same format as my key, e.g.,

```
b'\x61\x61\x9aF\x95=A?\xef\xc3a*\xdb :\xc6\x1bC'
```

Which means that I added a and a to the beginning of the code.

I don't know what this code is called so I could not find a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the base 10 integer value represented by each byte using list():

```
b = b'\x9aF\x95=A?\xef\xc3a*\xdb :\xc6\x1bC'
list(b)
# [154, 70, 149, 61, 65, 63, 239, 195, 97, 42, 219, 32, 58, 198, 27, 67]
```

It doesn't seem like the bytes represent anything meaningful in ASCII, in particular since a bunch of bytes are outside the ASCII range...

Edit: To prefix two bytes, you can just concatenate

```
b1 = b'aa' + b'\x9aF\x95=A?\xef\xc3a*\xdb :\xc6\x1bC'
```

Comment: Thanks, your output is not what I wanted, it is just an encryption key, so yes it will not represent something meaningful, but I just want to add two prefix bytes to it

Comment: I amended my answer. Otherwise you need to better explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, getting closer, but isn't the \x means they are in hex? so what I need is to have the 'aa' converted to \x and added to the key, so it would like like this; ``` \x61 + \x61\+ x9aF\x95=A?\xef\xc3a*\xdb :\xc6\x1bC' = b'\x61\x61\x9aF\x95=A?\xef\xc3a*\xdb :\xc6\x1bC'```

Comment: To concatenate, you need a bytes object. There are multiple ways to create one. The hex notation is just a way to represent the byte value. Maybe what you need is `bytes('a', 'ASCII') + b` or `(97).to_bytes(1, 'big') + b`